# Installing WindowBuilder on Eclipse 4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, installation, windowbuilder

I'm using Eclipse Juno 4.2, downloaded from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-42-rc2/junorc2).

On previous installs, I've been using 3.7, and I've been using WindowBuilder, which I find very useful. I noticed it wasn't included this time, so I used [this update site](http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.2/) provided on [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php) (the zip file download gives a "file unavailable" error).

However, when I run the install, it rapidly climbs to 28%, then freezes. After half an hour, I get a very long error, whose message starts with this text:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>
> context was:(profile=epp.package.java,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=).
>
> Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
>   Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.2/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.core_1.5.0.r42x201205291332.jar.pack.gz.

([full text](http://pastebin.com/JCVpqjcb))

Does anyone know how I can go about installing it?

Comment: As an addition, here a post with pictures that shows step-by-step how to install WindowBuilder in Eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13671987/814702

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try the juno repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/.

In Eclipse:

1. Goto - Menu > Help > Install New Software...
2. Select - Work With: Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
3. The WindowBuilder items are under "General Purpose Tools" (or use the filter)

Answer (score 7):

Installing WindowBuilder from this link http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201209281200/4.2/ - just add a new updatesite.

Other versions: 
Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) - http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.3/
Eclipse 3.8 (Juno) - http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201302221200/3.8/

Answer (score 2):

For Juno, I downloaded the archive update site from: http://eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201306261200/WB_v1.6.0_UpdateSite_for_Eclipse4.2.zip

Then I added the site as an archive to eclipse and installed the components just fine.  For some reason the update URL did not work for me after setting up my proxy.  Hope this helps!