# Is WindowBuilder Pro already installed in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder, gui-designer

At this page: https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-wbpro, there is no option to install WindowBuilder Pro to Eclipse Juno (4.2).

Is WindowBuilder Pro already installed with Eclipse Juno?

Also, is there a better free alternative to WindowBuilder Pro?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### UPDATE 2019

Again WindowBuilder Pro is no longer included in any of the latest Eclipse versions. So you need to add it as was shown in the initial answer below.

It is also strange, that WindowBuilder Pro is not available when searching Eclipse Market place (checked with the latest as of now version of Eclipse For Enterprise Java Developers ***version 2019-09***) despite the fact that the product's [website](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) is available.

But at least the related repository URL for the latest version of WindowBuilder Pro is now much compact and intuitive:

> http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/latest/

[image]

---

### UPDATE 2014

As Sean Lynch noted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22322724/814702) WindowBuilder is included in [Eclipse IDE for Java](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/lunar). Actually, it was already included there since version 3.7 ([Eclipse Indigo](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigosr2)), which was released in year 2011.

Note that currently, it is included by default **only** in the version for *Java Developers*, **NOT** in the version for [*Java **EE** Developers*](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunar), which is the most downloaded and wanted version. So for the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers you still need to install it yourself.

---

## Old answer

It is not installed by default in Eclipse.

The new WindowBuilder Pro home page is here:
http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/
On that page, in the "Current Status" section on the right, it says (emphasis mine):

> "Welcome to the **new** WindowBuilder homepage!"

---

### How to install WindowBuilder in Eclipse.

1) Copy the correct *link* for your version of Eclipse from the **Update Site** column (**Release Version**) on the [download page](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php):

[image]

2) In the Eclipse main menu choose **Help > Install new Software...**

[image]

3) In the appeared window click **Add...** button:

[image]

4) In the appeared dialog box, in the **Name** field write some descriptive name (like "WindowBuilder Pro") and paste the correct link (see step 1) in the **Location** field. After that click the **OK** button:

[image]

5) Select all the checkboxes that are going to appear, then click **Next** button and install WindowBuilder:

[image]

---

Another way to add a link to the list of available Software Sites:
in the Eclipse main menu choose **Window > Preferences**, in the preferences window choose **Install/Update > [Available Software Sites](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-p2-siteprefs.htm?cp=0_4_1_10)**, click **Add...** button and go on as described above.

---

As for the better alternative, well, seems like WindowBuilder Pro is the most preferred: [Best GUI designer for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426/best-gui-designer-for-eclipse)

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is the different of WindowBuilder Pro or WindowBuilder non-Pro version?

Comment: @Cheung I never saw that there are two versions (Pro and non-Pro). "Pro" is just part of the name, and often times the name of this plug-in is used without the "Pro". For instance on the official page you can see both variants (with and without "Pro") are used: https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

Answer (score 1):

WindowBuilder seems to be the best gui designer at the moment, since it can parse and work with any manually written code, it doesn't require any additional files(xmls etc). And it always tries to make the smallest change possible to the code.

Answer (score 1):

WindowBuilder is now included in Eclipse IDE for Java Developers.

[eclipse-java-kepler-SR2-win32.zip](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Comment: Actually WindowBuilder is included Eclipse IDE for Java Developers since version 3.7 (Eclipse Indigo), which was released in year 2011.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE FEB 2017**

As of Neon, it is no longer included:  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/neon2.

Please check that website for any future updates, as it could change at any time.

Note that you can also easily obtain WindowBuilder from the Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: This answer has been OBE ("overcome by events")

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get WindowBuilder on a computer that is connected to the internet, it's easy.  "[Use Eclipse Marketplace.](http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.6/)"

If your computer is not connected to the internet (can't access Eclipse Marketplace), you'll have to do something different for Neon and Oxygen:

Using the first link in the old answer, you'll click on the "Integration Version" "link" for the version you're interested in (4.6, 4.7, etc...).  On that page you'll be told something like "You're close!  This URL is an Eclipse software repository; you must use it in Eclipse (see how)."

However, you can do it yourself by clicking on "Show Directory Contents" (just down a bit and to the left).

Click on 'repository.zip' and download it.  Unzip it.

In Eclipse, choose 'Help->Install New Software...'
Click 'Add...' in the "Install" dialog.
Click 'Local...' in the "Add Repository" dialog and select the unzipped repository folder in the "Browse For Folder" dialog.  Click "OK" in these two dialogs and you'll find yourself back in the "Install" window.

You should see "WindowBuilder" in the large white-space.  Click "Select All" and "Next >".  There may be some problems with SWT.  You may end up at a page called the "Install Remediation Page".  Click 'Next >'.

On the 'Install Details' page, click 'Next >'.

Agree to the license (click "I accept..."), and click 'Finish'.

You'll need to restart Eclipse.

Done.