# WindowBuilder plugin eclipse for Helios Eclipse3.6.2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to add WindowsBuilder plug-in in my current Eclipse to use JIDE.. Am using Helios Eclipse 3.6.2
I followed the instructions mentioned in this link:
[Is WindowBuilder Pro already installed in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391544/is-windowbuilder-pro-already-installed-in-eclipse#new-answer)

and the URL of the plug-in I provided is
http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201306261200/3.6/

But it failed telling these reasons:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed:

```
WindowBuilder XML Core (requires Eclipse WTP/WST) 1.6.0.r36x201305211955 (org.eclipse.wb.core.xml.feature.feature.group 1.6.0.r36x201305211955)
  Missing requirement: WindowBuilder Core for XML GUI's 1.6.0.r36x201305211955 (org.eclipse.wb.core.xml 1.6.0.r36x201305211955) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WindowBuilder XML Core (requires Eclipse WTP/WST) 1.6.0.r36x201305211955 (org.eclipse.wb.core.xml.feature.feature.group 1.6.0.r36x201305211955)
    To: org.eclipse.wb.core.xml [1.6.0.r36x201305211955]
```

Comment: i have posted the solution, are u able to resolve ?

Answer (score 2):

This link might b useful to you!

Using [WindowBuilder](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/eclipse/795-using-windowbuilder-design-gui-eclipse.html) to design GUI in Eclipse (Helios).

Regarding your error! resolved from [Mark Ingram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/986/mark-ingram)

> The Google Plugin for Eclipse depends on other specific Eclipse
>   components, such as WST. Your installation of Eclipse may not yet
>   include all of them, but they can be easily installed by following
>   these instructions. Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)
>
> 1- Select Help > Install New Software...
>
> 2- Click the link for Available Software Sites.
>
> 3- Ensure there is an update site named Helios. If this is not
>   present, click Add... and enter
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios for the Location.
>
> 4- Now go through the installation steps; Eclipse should download and
>   install the plugin's dependencies.

Or check this [link](http://www.shekhargovindarajan.com/tips-n-tricks/solved-requires-bundle-org-eclipse-wst-xml-core-error-while-installing-google-plugin-in-fedora-eclipse/)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.. I selected only the checkbox containing WST and continued with installtaion..From past 3 hours it has reached only 50% and in between I got couple of pop ups like 'An internal error occurred during: "Install download3".
Comparison method violates its general contract!

An internal error occurred during: "Install download1".
Comparison method violates its general contract!'

Comment: @kushi can you download new helios or latest eclipse ide and follow above steps... may b it will work for you