# Can you create a GUI in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, ide

I am learning Java and my IDE is Eclipse Mars. I was wondering if there was a way to create a GUI in Eclipse?

I researched it and the only half decent way I can find was pretty complex, any ideas?

Comment: eclipse is an editor. you write code, and THAT code would create your gui.

Comment: The Eclipse Rich Client Platform (RCP) allows you to build a GUI using Eclipse as the framework.  Eclipse is also an integrated development environment (IDE) that allows you to write code in Java and other languages to construct a GUI.  GUI building is complex and takes some experience to get correct.

Comment: Related: [Is WindowBuilder Pro already installed in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13671987/814702)

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse includes [WindowBuilder](https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/), a "bi-directional Java GUI designer." Whether you have it installed in your Eclipse depends on which package you downloaded; if you downloaded **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** then it's already included. If you got a different package, you can install WindowBuilder via [these instructions](https://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php).

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse itself has only the coding function when it comes to GUIs.

If you really want to know your way around GUIs I recommend you learn it by programming it.

If you just want to try it out one time or start with easier lessons and then go into programming it yourself I recommend the IDE "Netbeans". It has a drag-and-drop kinda GUI builder implemented with which GUIs are very easy to implement.

Especially if your are just learning Java I recommend learning the basics in Java first, insert your functions into an easy to build GUI with Netbeans and later on go into fully programming GUIs.

Netbeans is also free and pretty much the same as eclipse. Maybe less customizable features, but for beginners and people who want to know how GUI works its perfect.

Comment: This is not an accurate answer; Eclipse does have WindowBuilder for WYSIWYG, drag-and-drop GUI development.

Comment: huh. my bad, didnt know