# error while installing WindowBuilder Pro Update Site - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7

Tags: eclipse, swing

I faced this error while installing http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7 on eclipse Juno Service Release 1

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer_2.6.0.r37x201206111227.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.GWTExt_2.6.0.r37x201206111253.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.GXT_2.6.0.r37x201206111253.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.GXT.databinding_2.6.0.r37x201206111253.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.SmartGWT_2.6.0.r37x201206111253.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.UiBinder_2.6.0.r37x201206111227.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.UiBinder.wizards_2.6.0.r37x201206111253.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.doc.user_2.6.0.r37x201206111253.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/features/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.editor.feature_2.6.0.r37x201206111227.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/features/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.feature_2.6.0.r37x201206111253.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted_2.6.0.r37x201206111222.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.2_0_2.6.0.r37x201206111222.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.2_0.super_2.6.0.r37x201206111222.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.2_0.webkit_2.6.0.r37x201206111222.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.2_0.webkit_win32x64_2.6.0.r37x201206111222.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.2_2_2.6.0.r37x201206111222.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.2_2.webkit_2.6.0.r37x201206111222.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/features/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.feature_2.6.0.r37x201206111222.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.lib_2.6.0.r37x201206111222.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.launch_2.6.0.r37x201206111253.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.preferences_2.6.0.r37x201206111253.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.wizards_2.6.0.r37x201206111253.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.rcp_1.5.0.r37x201206111317.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.GroupLayout_1.5.0.r37x201206111330.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/features/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.GroupLayout_support.feature_1.5.0.r37x201206111330.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.SWT_AWT_1.5.0.r37x201206111333.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/features/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.SWT_AWT_support_1.5.0.r37x201206111333.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.databinding_1.5.0.r37x201206111317.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.databinding.emf_1.5.0.r37x201206111317.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.databinding.xwt_1.5.0.r37x201206111323.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.doc.user_1.5.0.r37x201206111236.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/features/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.doc.user.feature_1.5.0.r37x201206111236.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/features/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.feature_1.5.0.r37x201206111317.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.nebula_1.5.0.r37x201206111317.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.rcp.swing2swt_1.5.0.r37x201206111317.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.swt_1.5.0.r37x201206111304.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/features/org.eclipse.wb.swt.feature_1.5.0.r37x201206111304.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.swt.layout.grouplayout_1.5.0.r37x201206111330.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.swt.widgets.baseline_1.5.0.r37x201206111317.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/plugins/org.eclipse.wb.xwt_1.5.0.r37x201206111323.jar
dl.google.com
Unknown Host: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7/features/org.eclipse.wb.xwt.feature_1.5.0.r37x201206111323.jar
dl.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are using for the Windowbuilder Pro Update Site does not exist.

Last I checked, the update site for Juno is: http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2

If that doesn't work, take a look at this question: [Installing WindowBuilder on Eclipse 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10867920/2081889)

Try that and get back to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the update sites directly at the eclipse webpage:

http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php