# Eclipse Juno WindowBuilder Palette is Empty

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder, palette

I'm using **Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) for Java EE** and just installed **WindowBuilder** plug-n. At this time I'm building Java SE Application with Swing components.

The `Palette` is **completely empty** (no widgets). Is it a sign of incomplete installation or have I (hopefully) missed something obvious?

I was able to select `New -> Other -> WindowBuilder -> Swing Designer -> JPanel`.

Not even sure what other information I need to provide.

Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**

I installed via `Help -> Install new software`  Followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867920/installing-windowbuilder-on-eclipse-4-2?rq=1).

What throws me off is that in Eclipse Community Forum I found [a post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/243146/730895/) which answering a similar question states: "*What you are seeing is the **expected behaviour**. Until you actually edit a UI class using WindowBuilder, those views will be empty.*".  I do not know how to interpret it.

**UPDATE: Problem solved**

When I created a new `JFrame` via `Create new visual classes` icon I finally got `Design` view as well as `Palette` full of components and normal `Structure` view.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a bad install to me.  How did you install it?

Comment: @Nathaniel Waisbrot - 
Added my answer to the original post.

Comment: I have had weird problems doing it that way in the past, and better results using the Eclipse Marketplace to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Palette view in Eclipse is tied to the currently active Editor.  So if you don't have an Editor or you have selected and focused on the Palette view, it will be empty.  So leave the palette view open, then create a JFrame java class.  Then right-click the Java Class and make sure you are opening it in the WindowBuilder editor.  Once the WindowBuilder visual editor is open, and you also have the Palette open, you should see the wigets populated there.

Comment: I have a class that extends `JFrame` that I created manually and a class that extends `JPanel` that was created by `WindowBuilder Wizard`. When I open **either** of these two classes with `WindowBuilder Editor` the `Palette` view is **completely empty**.

Answer (score 0):

Check if pallet is open in view pannel (parallel to console, progress and all), if it is open close that, then pannel will appear automatically in windowsBuilder tool.

Answer (score 0):

go to menu, window/Show view in the menu and enable palete option.