# Palette is blank on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, windowbuilder, palette

My palette is not showing any widgets on eclipse.
I installed the latest window builder software but still no sign of any widget.

I found this similar issue on stack overflow--> [Eclipse Juno WindowBuilder Palette is Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963082/eclipse-juno-windowbuilder-palette-is-empty)
But I still can't understand how to fix it.
Can someone help me fix this.

[image: Click here to see how my palette looks like]

Comment: Does the following help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67430120/6505250

Comment: @howlger nope, still not working

Comment: At least it should help to improve your question: What is the exact version of the WindowBuilder you installed in which version of Eclipse? What is the content of the .java file you opened with WindowBuilder? Is the .java file located in a source folder, is it free of compile errors and the project free of build errors? Do you have a `module-info.java` file and if so, with what content? Unfortunately, you cropped your screenshot, so it's not possible to see it from that either.