# Installing WindowBuilder on 64-bit Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I downloaded the Windows 64-bit version of Eclipse.

I went to "Help | Install New Software..." and entered the following URL to get WindowBuilder.

Kepler 4.3 (4.4 does not have a link yet)
http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201309271200/4.3/

I then saw the following display:

[image]

The text of the error is:

```
Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"WindowBuilder GroupLayout Support" will be ignored because a newer version is already     installed. 
"SWT Designer XWT Support (requires Eclipse WTP/WST)" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
"Swing Designer Documentation" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
"Swing Designer" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
"SWT Designer Documentation" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
"SWT Designer Core" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
"WindowBuilder Core UI" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
"SWT Designer SWT_AWT Support" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
"SWT Designer" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
"WindowBuilder Core Documentation" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
"WindowBuilder Core" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
"WindowBuilder Java Core" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed. 
"WindowBuilder XML Core (requires Eclipse WTP/WST)" will be ignored because a newer version is already installed.
```

I am not allowed to continue.

Pressing cancel and then new project | Other yields no WindowBuilder.

At one point, on a previous installation attempt (I subsequently deleted the contents of the folder and recopied from the zip file.), I got the URL to work, but there was no SWT, just Swing and WindowBuilder. On that attempt, The "Install New Software..." and 2 other links disappeared from the Help menu, so I deleted everything, as I said. I then tried again, but keep seeing this error.

What newer version?

Thought:
1. This morning I had jre 1.7 and jre 1.6 installed on my system, but did not see a point to jre 1.6, so I uninstalled the older version. I did restart the machine afterwards. I notice in the WindowBuilder versions column, see the image, that it says 1.6.1.43. I presume that has nothing to do with jre 1.7? The Window Preferences dialog shows jre 1.7, so I do not think so.

[image]

How do I get WindowBuilder/SWT/Swing to install on the 64-bit Eclipse?

UPDATE (will comment on comment shortly):
I saw [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867920/installing-windowbuilder-on-eclipse-4-2?rq=1) on StackOverflow, which said to type in Kepler in the install new software.

I did that and got punished for it, but at least I can forward the images. Basically, the "Install New Software..." menu option and two others disappear, and there is no WindowBuilder on the new project other.

[image]

[image]

Basically, I think that Eclipse is not quite ready for prime time and has bugs.

I will try to find and download the integrated version. I remember doing that once before, but did not see the integrated version at the eclipse [download page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), so I downloaded what I saw.

(Okay, I see that link. I just did not realize that was that.)

I am still new to Java programming, as I come from a Microsoft background.

Comment: Why dont just redownlaod eclipse ? its small. Use ( Eclipse IDE for Java Developers) it include window builder already.Then you can download all other parts by going into donwload install new software of whathever is that tab called. Place *eclipse name(kepler,juno etc.) and you will be able to see all the plugins you can install.That is with no hassle if you dont mind to download again.Im kinda confused why it doesnt let you install it again :/ .Never had trouble with that.

Comment: You have part of the answer Tomas. I got back to an earlier error. Installing "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" and then installing SWT by typing in Kepler in the "Install New Software" does install SWT, so that you can get "Menu | File | New | Projects | Other | WindowBuilder | SWT | Application Window", but that sadly yields the "Folder xxx does not exist" error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is identical to the answer that I gave in question [22099190](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099190/how-to-get-window-builders-swt-designer-in-64-bit-eclipse). I am copying the answer here. The answer applies to 32-bit or to 64-bit Eclipse.

**Installation Instructions**

1. [Download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR2/eclipse-java-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip) 'Eclipse IDE for Java Developers', not the EE version.
2. Extract the files using WinZip, 7-Zip, or whatever, just not Windows built-in tool. See installation notes on Eclipse download page for this requirement. NOTE: **DO NOT place files in the "C:\Program Files" folder on Windows 7.** See [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/326451/) for note.
3. **BEFORE** starting eclipse.exe, go to the environment settings and define the HOME variable and set that to %USERPROFILE%. You will need to log out and then log back in. Windows will not read the environment settings without doing this set and as such Eclipse.
4. Install [PortableGit-1.8.4-preview20130916](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=PortableGit-1.8.4-preview20130916.7z) and add the path in the PATH variable.
5. Start Eclipse.
6. Go to "Menu > Help > Install New Software..." and type in kepler. Select the SWT and WindowBuilder from the list. It was supposed to come prebundled, but did not, better this way. You will need to restart Eclipse.
7. Turn on the error log, "Menu > Windows > Show View > Error Log" to see any other errors that might exist.

I am still working on the EGit warning, but SWT exists.

I tried these steps repeatedly (deleting Eclipse folder and trying again) and the steps worked each of the times that I tried it. Yay!

Comment: Whoever gave a down vote, I would like to know the why. Simply voting down without an explanation does not give any learning experience. This issue was quite real and I gave full explanations to help others that might run into the problem. I would like to learn what reasons you had.

Answer (score 0):

Install the newest version of eclipse (E.g. Luna) (Fine for EE too).

Install the WindowBuilder plug-in through help->Install new software by providing the link "http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/4.2".

Update the plug-in through Help->Check for updates.

Cheers.  :)

Shevon Silva.