# Eclipse 64-bit gives "Folder xxx does not exist" error, when trying to create a new project

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, windowbuilder

I am trying to still solve my other [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083207), but arguably this side problem is a separate topic, so I am posting this request separately.

I downloaded "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" from the Eclipse website (Kepler, Windows, 64-bit). I placed the contents into a folder, "C:\Program Files\Development\Tools\Eclipse", and proceeded to install SWT. I went to "Menu > Help > Install New Software..." and entered kepler. I then went to 'General Productivity Tools' and selected the SWT components. After restarting, I had SWT installed.

I then went to "Menu > File > New > Other... > WindowBuilder > SWT Designer > SWT > Application Window" and clicked on next. That yields the following image. My OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

[image]

The folder exists just fine. Forward slashes or backwards slashes, no slashes, browse, whatever, I tried it all, and the error is the same. How can I bypass this error?

Am I looking at a bug with the 64-bit Eclipse? I did try restarting my computer, and the installation is fresh.

Comment: I uninstalled Java JRE 1.6 this morning. I do have Java JRE 1.7, which Eclipse says it uses, but I am wondering if the older version might be tied to Eclipse. An interesting note is that Eclipse adds a new task to the taskbar with the options "New Task..., Activate Task..., and close window". If I select either of the first two, I get the error "Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error. A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.". Could these errors be related?

Comment: I might know the problem. I just ran into this note, sadly after uninstalling the JDK and all my JREs. The note is at "http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation", which states that the internal Windows zip decompressor has issues with Eclipse. I might have run into that. Unbelievable. I will not shortly. An installation utility would have done wonders.

Answer (score 2):

The following might be obvious to experienced uses, but not to newbies like me and there is no single location that I found that spells out how to create a project, so here are the instructions.

NEW SWT PROJECT INSTRUCTIONS (applies to other types too, concept is here)

Note: The folder is relative, not absolute.

Follow these steps.

1. Go to "Menu > File > New > Project...". Create a new project. Follow the prompts.
2. Go to "Menu > File > New > Other..." and select "WindowBuilder > SWT Designer > SWT > Application Window", click on the next button.
3. The Source folder text box now comes pre-populated to the project name along with the src subfolder. The package name is also there. Enter the name and click on finish.

You cannot create a new SWT application window project directly. That was the problem. You must create a "Menu > File > New > Project..." project first. Sadly, the names project are identical and different meanings.

1. Oh yes, you must install the SWT jar into the build path libraries (external jar) too.
2. Start the development work.

Comment: Wow ... i thought it was tha application builder wizard who create my project. It's so stupid.... Thank's for the answer you save my time ;)