# Installing WindowBuilder on Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I'm using Eclipse Neon, that I installed from Eclipse Installer.The problem is when I want to work with Swing, I did not find it.

And when I tried to installed using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867920/installing-windowbuilder-on-eclipse-4-2) solution, I did not find it in the repository of neon.
Can Anyone help ?

Comment: Probably in the Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: @greg-449, I tried Marketplace but unfortunately I found nothing :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Starting today, there is a more official build for WindowBuilder on Neon: http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.6/ . You can monitor progress of the re-introduction of WindowBuilder into Neon.1 at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=498276 .

Answer (score 17):

To install WindowBuilder in Eclipse Neon go to :
Eclipse Help-> Install New Software.
In the textbox for add enter this URL :
 http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.6/ (as shown in screenshot)
Tick the Window Builder and click Add . Complete the installation.
[image: WindowBuilder]

Comment: Can this be used with offline computers?  Can it be transferred?

Comment: Don't forget to turn on "Group items by category"

Comment: I followed the above, but when I go to File -> New -> Other, I couldnt find Windwbbuilders in there. I go to Help -> Installatrion Details, WB is indeed installed. Hope yo have advice

Answer (score 0):

See http://zaunerc.blogspot.fr/2016/06/windowbuilder-p2-update-site-for.html . Someone created a Neon-compatible build of WindowBuilder to consume until WindowBuilder officially provide a compatible alternative.

Comment: Thank you, this one worked (at least, as a temporary solution), I just Added a new repository using this Location : `https://dl.bintray.com/zaunerc/p2/org.eclipse.windowbuilder.p2_site/latest/`