# Eclipse WindowBuilder in Linux is broken

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

The WindowBuilder is broken I can't add some of the components. When I try to do it:

Here is the error message

[image: error]

And when I try to add the component

Widow Builder was not able to show the GUI.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.java6.model.SwingVisualMapper.getComponentPreferredSize(SwingVisualMapper.java:85)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.form.layoutdesign.LayoutDesigner.endMoving(LayoutDesigner.java:596)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.layout.group.model.GroupLayoutSupport.command_create(GroupLayoutSupport.java:277)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.layout.group.gef.GroupLayoutEditPolicy2$4.executeEdit(GroupLayoutEditPolicy2.java:510)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.core.gef.command.EditCommand$1.run(EditCommand.java:52)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.run(ExecutionUtils.java:324)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.core.gef.command.EditCommand.execute(EditCommand.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.internal.gef.core.EditDomain.executeCommand(EditDomain.java:59)
>       at org.eclipse.wb.gef.core.tools.Tool.executeCommand(Tool.java:209)

I tried to add it manually and it worked. 
The other problem is when I try to add any component, it creates it and after the creation Window Builder stuck. To fix it I have to return back to the source code wait 1-2 minutes. And I have to do this every time after I add new component. 
[This happens when I try to add a JLabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRSyr.png)
I don't know if these bugs are because of Linux or it's just something wrong in my java/eclipse configuration. Are there any solutions?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse luna for linux 64 bit

Comment: Please consider updating to Neon then, to take advantage of the various patches that have happened in the last 2 years. Beware, WindowBuilder isn't part of Neon.0, you'll need to install it as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058676/installing-windowbuilder-on-eclipse-neon until neon.1 is released (in a couple of weeks).

Comment: Thank you. I updated it to eclipse neon and it works perfect.